# How to create documentation for Python variables that will be visible in PyCharm quick documentation functionality?

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a file named `PushButtonType.py` where I define two variables:

```
OK = 0  # acts like a OK button.

""" acts like a cancel button. """
CANCEL = 0
```

In another file, I import and use those variables:

```
from PushButtonType import CANCEL, OK

foo = CANCEL
bar = OK
```

I want the comments from the first file to be visible in the Quick Documentation (Ctrl+Q) functionality of PyCharm. Currently, when I put a cursor on one of the variables and press Ctrl+Q, I get a message saying "No documentation found" (see screenshot below).

I would like the comments be visible in the Quick documentation popup. How can I do this? Is there some special format of comments?

[image: Quick documentation popup in PyCharm]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [2018.2 EAP](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/):

```
bar = 1
"""bar variable"""
```

[image]