# PyCharm: How to get class attributes to be listed in Quick Documentation pop-up?

Tags: python, pycharm, documentation, docstring

I found this really annoying that Quick Documentation doesn't show attributes, listed in class' docsting. I thought that the reason was incorrect or unsupported docstring format, but behavior is the same for both `reST` and `Google` styles (I set them properly in `Python Integrated Tools`).

---

My current docstring style is `Google`. Let me show what's wrong in pictures:

Here's `Actor` class.
[image] 
As you see, `Attributes` section presents in docstring but not in Quick Documentation pop-up.

Also, there is no annotation on attribute `world_id`. 
[image]

`Args` of `__init__` recognition works like a charm. 
[image]

Let's add docstring directly to attribute (how it was suggested in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51427188/10380652)). Works great, isn't it?
[image]

And call Quick Documentation for attribute inside another method. Wow, there's no description again.
[image]

---

**How to get things working?** How to set up PyCharm so it catch up class' attributes and show 'em in Quick Documentation?

PyCharm 2018.2.4 (Community Edition). Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: In the PyCharm documentation, it says that "PyCharm recognizes inline documentation created in accordance with [PEP-257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/)".

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf, there's line in PEP-257: "The docstring for a class should summarize its behavior and list the public methods and instance variables". I suppose that's enough for PyCharm to recognize attributes.

Answer (score 7):

Here's how I managed to display class attributes in the Docstring in Pycharm 2020.3.3 (I use professional edition) :

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    """
    A Test model to see the class attributes in the docstring

    Attributes:

    - :class:`str` name --> The name of the test object
    - :class:`datetime` created_at --> Date and time when the instance was created
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Note that without the `Attributes:` line, it won't work as expected.

And this is how it is shown in the quick documentation :

[image]

Comment: the more pythonic way would be:

Comment: ```name :    :class:`str` ```

Answer (score 5):

For anyone who is still struggling with this and stumbles upon this post (as I did).

PyCharm doesn't support this currently - or should I rather say that it still doesn't support it. Not for Google style docstring, neither for structuredText. There are multiple tickets regarding this issue on their Youtrack support website.

E.g. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-17945 - this issue sits there for over 5 years!